# RapidWeaver Theme to Drupal6 Theme

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming, drupal-themes

I am working on a site which has a RapidWeaver Theme ( f_fusion ). But I am more of a developer than a designer. Is there any way for us to convert a RapidWeaver theme easily to a Drupal6 theme so that all the styling remains the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, particularly if you're a developer since it's really a question of taking the HTML & CSS from the RapidWeaver Theme and placing Drupal variables in it.

Start with checking this link to get an overall idea about [Drupal Theming](http://drupal.org/theme-guide/6-7)

When you know how to create a basic theme structure, you should learn how to modify the page.tpl.php file to start with, after that it will of course depends on the specifics of your site but you definitely should be on your way.

If you want to dig deeper, check this book: [Pro Drupal Development](http://www.apress.com/9781590597552/)

Comment: Yes, Patrick, I started doing the same and am partially successful. Thanks a lot for your answer :)